# iPhone SDK - How to check files' name in document folder?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Users can upload images (jpg or png) from computer to iPhone, and images will be stored in app document folder.

My questions are

1. how to check the names of images that are currently in document folder?
2. how to identify it is a jpg or png?

Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 1):

The files uploaded via iTunes can be found in the app's document folder:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 // Get documents folder
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

In there, get the files and check the extension to find out if it is JPG, PNG or whatever.